# Are there any guarantees about the order of elements that select returns?

Tags: clojure, seesaw

I have a nine textboxes nested inside of vertical panels that I want grab the text from and use. For convenience, I'm just using `select` to grab them by class, then applying them to the constructor of a record. Basically something like:

```
(ns example.core
    (:require [seesaw.core :as sc]))

(apply ->RecordConstructor
       (sc/select root [:.textbox]))
```

This *seems* to work as I expect, but I haven't been able to find anything official on what defines the order that `select` returns its elements in.

It seems to be based on the order that the elements were given to their parent. Is this correct?

Comment: What is the `sc` namespace?

Comment: @AlanThompson Whoops. That's my alias for the seesaw core. I'll just remove it since the question is tagged with seesaw.

Comment: Personally I'd vastly prefer if you instead put a `(ns foo.core (:require [seesaw.core :as sc]))`  or `(require '[,,, :as sc])` before the snippet. Clojure core has hundreds of vars and it can be hard to know what's coming from where. Especially in a snippet here on this site, outside of a codebase where you have a shared context. (Even inside of a codebase I prefer to (almost) never :refer or :use anything, but what you do behind closed doors is between you and the people you work with.) Just my 2c.

Comment: @madstap Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert, but it looks like seesaw just does a depth-first tree walk of its document model. So there's nothing guaranteed, but sure, it sounds like you will get things in that order: depth-first, leftmost-first. Here "left" is whatever order seesaw stores its stuff in, not necessarily display order. Again I don't know what order that is, but your guess of "the order you added stuff to the model" seems as good as any to me.